# The .apk file for my built game is much larger than expected

Tags: unity, android, build-process

Assets of my game are 15 MB, Player Settings are default, but my `.apk` file is 45 MB. I tried to change Player Settings and convert PNG images to JPEG, but this didn't work.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Comment: Have you reviewed [past Q&A about reducing the size of a built Unity game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+build+size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- question was changed after writing the original answer --

One thing you can do is unzip the APK (it is basically just a renamed zip file) and look inside.

Don't forget that your binary + any icons/logos/etc assets take up more space. It might also include debug symbols, 1x/2x/etc resized assets.

Comment: The question poster is asking about storage, not memory, indicated by his mentioning of `.apk` file which is nothing to do with memory.

Comment: the question was changed after I wrote this answer

Answer (score 0):

The `.apk` file is also be bundling itself with manifests and necessary data files that make an `.apk` work as an installer package (because that's what `.apk`'s are. They're an installer.)

 I had the same problem with extracting my small amount of assets and getting a file way larger than I thought. You should be okay, as this is not a problem, just Unity doing its job right.